# Is WPF purely case-sensitive? Is "Auto" value in width field case-sensitive?

Tags: wpf, xaml, width

This is a v.basic question for WPF.

At first glance, it seems that WPF is case-sensitive. But if this has to be true then how come width="auto" & width="Auto" both works fine? On the other hand if is case-insensitive then why do controls don't accept 'width' as its property? You can define the width of a control only using 'Width' (Capital W).

[Consolidated answer link](http://codereferences.blogspot.in/2012/02/is-wpf-purely-case-sensitive.html)

Comment: yes it will, it is not case-sensitive, but why not just try?

Comment: I thought someone will put up more light on it. I just tried it works, so want to know if it is true or something more in my code done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half true.

From the official [XAML Overview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#case_and_whitespace_in_xaml)

> XAML is generally speaking case sensitive. For purposes of resolving backing types, WPF XAML is case sensitive by the same rules that the CLR is case sensitive. Object elements, property elements, and attribute names must all be specified by using the sensitive casing when compared by name to the underlying type in the assembly, or to a member of a type. XAML language keywords and primitives are also case sensitive. Values are not always case sensitive. Case sensitivity for values will depend on the type converter behavior associated with the property that takes the value, or the property value type. For example, properties that take the Boolean type can take either true or True as equivalent values, but only because the native WPF XAML parser type conversion for string to Boolean already permits these as equivalents.

In general XAML IS case sensitive but the property values are not always since that depends on the property converter, so in most cases it work such as where `Auto` is the same as `auto`, although in some special cases the property converter might not be able to handle them with case-insensitivity

**Note:** We are talking about property `values` here and not property `names`

Comment: This is something I was looking for... Thanks Kypros.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [FrameworkElement.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> In addition to acceptable Double values, this property can also be Double.NaN. This is how you specify auto sizing behavior. **In XAML you set the value to the string "Auto" (case insensitive)** to enable the auto sizing behavior.

So, `Auto` (case-insensitive) is just a XAML shorthand for setting the property to [`Double.NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Right from [**MSDN: FrameworkElement.Width Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx):

> In XAML you set the value to the string "Auto" (case insensitive) to enable the auto sizing behavior.